How to connect PHP oci8_19 with oracle free 23.5.0-lite
it's my first using oracle database, i've run container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:23.5.0.0-lite container and it's working fine with this credential localhost:1521 as sysdba, sys:12345678 FREEPDB1
and it's working fine when i tried to connect via sqlplus inside container, or maybe dbeaver from my windows 11. But the problem is, it's not connect from my codeigniter project.
I've enbale php extension oci8_19, i've setup the codeigniter database like this
'hostname' => 'localhost:1521/SYSDBA',
'username' => 'sys',
'password' => '12345678',
'database' => 'FREEPDB1',
'dbdriver' => 'oci8',

but, i got error like this
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: oci_connect(): ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Filename: oci8/oci8_driver.php

Line Number: 238

Backtrace:

File: D:\project\application\third_party\ion_auth\models\Ion_auth_model.php
Line: 174
Function: database

File: D:\project\application\third_party\ion_auth\libraries\Ion_auth.php
Line: 71
Function: model

File: D:\project\application\core\MY_Controller.php
Line: 9
Function: __construct

File: D:\project\application\controllers\Auth.php
Line: 9
Function: __construct

File: D:\project\index.php
Line: 320
Function: require_once

how to solve this? do i need to use another php extension?
I've expect it's connected normally via codeigniter or another php project, cause it's connected from my dbeaver or sqlplus.

You are using the 'easy connect' syntax, so hostname should be 'localhost:1521/FREEPDB1'. The part after the / is the service name. You currently have SYSDBA, which is a role name, not a service name; and as you're connecting as SYS you probably need to include that. It isn't something I've done but based on other clients you might want something like:
'hostname' => 'localhost:1521/FREEPDB1',
'username' => 'sys AS SYSDBA',
'password' => '12345678',
'database' => '',
'dbdriver' => 'oci8',

You should only connect as SYS to perform DBA tasks. For normal work create a new user with just the necessary privileges and connect using that instead (without the SYSDBA role).
